# Python: Expected an indented block outside for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indentation

can someone please explain why I keep getting error message: 'expected an indented block' in this python code? The code was working before, but now I keep getting this message on IDLE when I try to run the code. I would appreciate any help. I included an image of the message too.

[image: Error Message]

```
`def coordinates():
"""
input none
output is a an array of the sequence of coordinates representing spaces inside and outside the bedroom
"""
sleepHistory = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
sleepHistory[0]=[0,0]
wakeUp = 0
escape = 0
start = [0,0]
one =[1,-1]



for i in range(1,6): 
    onestep = random.choice(one)
    facing = direction()
    if((facing == 'down') or (facing == 'up')):
        start =  [start[0] + onestep, start[1]]
        sleepHistory[i] = start

    if((facing == 'right') or facing == 'left'):
        start = [start[0], start[1] + onestep]
        sleepHistory[i] = start
if (sleepHistory[2] == [0,0] or sleepHistory[2] == sleepHistory[4]):
    return coordinates();
if ((sleepHistory[1] == sleepHistory[3]) or (sleepHistory[3] == sleepHistory[5])):
    return coordinates();
return sleepHistory`
```

Comment: perhaps you are mixing tabs and spaces for indentation

Comment: If you would take a minute to learn the proper way to include code, I could have checked how you indented it. It's easier and quicker to do it the proper way too.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have tabs set up to be at spacing of 4 . Your code could look like this

```
    for i in range(1,6):                 # indented by one tab
        onestep = random.choice(one)    # indented by 8 spaces
```

But Python counts one tab to be equivalent to a spacing of 8

So the block *looks* indented, but isn't according to Python